# Get multiple descendants using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some search results appearing at the bottom of my HTML page, and I want to grab some contents of each `li` element appearing in these results:

```
<ul id="hits">

  <li class="hit">
    <a href="#" class="image" style="background-image: url('http://...')"></a>
    <div class="anotherclass">
      <h5 class="title"> Here is a title </h5>
      <p> Here is some paragraph text </p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>...</li>

</ul>
```

I need these two elements from each `li` (in this order):

1. the text inside the `h5` tag (i.e., "Here is a title"),
2. and the image path appearing as an attribute inside the anchor `a` tag (i.e.,`background-image: url()`)

So far this has been my solution, but no luck:

```
$(".hit").each(function() {
  let title = $(this).find("title").innerHTML;
  let img = $(this).find("image").attr("style");
});
```

I'm also not sure how to get the URL inside of the `style` attribute, but maybe that's another SO question.

Comment: You are missing a `.`, should be `.find(".title")`, `.find(".image")`

Comment: use `$(this).find(".image").css("background-image")` to get url

Comment: Thanks, in my original code there was indeed a period `.` missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".hit").each(function() {
  let title = $(this).find(".title").text();
  let img = $(this).find(".image").css('background-image');
});
```

i think you mean to use classes.

Comment: All the posted answers are good. I'm choosing this one because it's the closest to what I was looking for (`.css(`background-image`)` gets me closer to extracting the actual image URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was close enough. Since `title` and `image` are classes, you need to add `.`. And secondly, to get the `h5`, you should use `text()` instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
$(".hit").each(function() {
  let title = $(this).find(".title").text();
  let img = $(this).find(".image").attr("style");
  console.log(title)
  console.log(img)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="hits">

  <li class="hit">
    <a href="#" class="image" style="background-image: url('http://...')"></a>
    <div class="anotherclass">
      <h5 class="title"> Here is a title </h5>
      <p> Here is some paragraph text </p>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of You are missing a `.`, should be `.find(".title")`, `.find(".image")`

Second to get the text from `h5` use `.text()` and not `innerHTML`

**Demo**

```js
$(".hit").each(function() {
  let title = $(this).find(".title").text();
  console.log(title)
  let img = $(this).find(".image").attr("style");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="hits">

  <li class="hit">
    <a href="#" class="image" style="background-image: url('http://...')"></a>
    <div class="anotherclass">
      <h5 class="title"> Here is a title </h5>
      <p> Here is some paragraph text </p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>...</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sxc3jad4/

you need add dot `(.)` if you want select element by class

- change find("title") to find(".title") //find element which have title class
- change innerHTML to text() //get text.
- change find("image") to find(".image") //find element which have image class
- change attr("style") to css("background-image") //get css value of property background-image